# How to select all items where LEN > 0

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to Google BigQuery, and I'm finding that the SQL really quite different from normal SQL.  I'm trying to select all items from a table that has data in a field named 'ticket_fields'.  I son't want nulls.  I tried the following:

```
WHERE COLUMN <> '' 

WHERE LEN(COLUMN) > 0

WHERE NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN)), '') IS NOT NULL
```

None of that worked.  How can I select all records where there are non-nulls from one specific field?

Answer (score 3):

In some systems, the empty string and `NULL` are treated equivalently (Oracle, for example). In BigQuery, these are distinct values, so:

```
-- Returns TRUE
SELECT CAST(NULL AS STRING) IS NULL

-- Returns NULL
SELECT LENGTH(CAST(NULL AS STRING)) > 0

-- Returns TRUE
SELECT CAST(NULL AS STRING) IS NULL

-- Returns FALSE
SELECT '' IS NULL

-- Returns FALSE
SELECT LENGTH('') > 0

-- Returns TRUE
SELECT '' IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to filter rows where the column is `NULL`, then use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.table WHERE column IS NOT NULL
```

If you want to filter rows where the column is empty *or* `NULL`, you can just check that the length is positive:

```
SELECT * FROM dataset.table WHERE LENGTH(column) > 0
```

This is because `LENGTH(column)` returns `NULL` if `column` is null, so the `WHERE` clause excludes the row.

Comment: Thanks for the look.  I just tried this: SELECT * FROM dataset.table WHERE LENGTH(column) > 0   I got this result: GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Unrecognized name: ticket_fields at [1:69]

Comment: Maybe you aren't actually using `SELECT *`, then. This is unrelated to the question that you asked.